# Trying to write "<<<" in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I am having trouble with the code below:

```
IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 rest <<< "$line"
```

Don't get me wrong this code works good but it doesn't seem to be used for ksh. I basically need to write the same code without the "<<<". There is not much info on the "<<<" online. If anybody has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Ok code is as follows for the entire portion of programming:

```
m|M)
            #Create Modify Message
            clear
            echo "                                 Modify Record                                 "
            echo -en '\n'
            echo -en '\n'
            while true
            do
                echo "What is the last name of the person you would like to modify:"
                read last_name
                if line=$(grep -i "^${last_name}:" "$2")
                then
                    oldIFS=$IFS 
                    IFS=:
                    set -- $line
                    IFS=$oldIFS
                    c1=$1
                    c2=$2
                    c3=$3
                    c4=$4
                    shift; shift; shift; shift 
                    rest="$*"
                    echo -e "Last Name: $1\nFirst Name: $2\nState: $4"
                    while true
                    do
                        echo "What would you like to change the state to?:"
                        read state
                            if echo $state | egrep -q '^[A-Z]{2}$'
                            then
                                echo "State: $state"
                                echo "This is a valid input"
                                break
                            else
                                echo "Not a valid input:"
                            fi
                    done
                    echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nState: $state"
                    echo "State value changed"
                    break                       
                else
                    echo "ERROR: $last_name is not in database"
                    echo "Would you like to search again (y/n):"
                    read modify_choice
                    case $modify_choice in [Nn]) break;; esac
                fi  
            done

;;
```

Ok so everything works except for the

```
echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nState: $state"
```

It will just show:

Last Name:

First Name:

State:

So I can see it is not adding it to my echo correctly.

**FINAL EDIT**

***CODE:***

```
#Case statement for modifying an entry
        m|M)
            #Create Modify Message
            clear
            echo "                                 Modify Record                                 "
            echo -en '\n'
            echo -en '\n'
            while true
            do
                echo "What is the last name of the person you would like to modify:"
                read last_name
                if line=$(grep -i "^${last_name}:" "$2")
                then
                    echo "$line" |
                    while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 rest; do
                        echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nState: $c4"
                        last=$c1
                        first=$c2
                    done
                    while true
                    do
                        echo "What would you like to change the state to?:"
                        read state
                            if echo $state | egrep -q '^[A-Z]{2}$'
                            then
                                echo "State: $state"
                                echo "This is a valid input"
                                break
                            else
                                echo "Not a valid input:"
                            fi
                    done
                    echo -e "Last Name: $last\nFirst Name: $first\nState: $state"
                    echo "State value changed"
                    break           
                else
                    echo "ERROR: $last_name is not in database"
                    echo "Would you like to search again (y/n):"
                    read modify_choice
                    case $modify_choice in [Nn]) break;; esac
                fi  
            done
 ;;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892215/grep-statement-in-if-then-else-statment-is-not-giving-intended-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) in Bash

```
command <<<"string"
```

is basically equivalent to

```
echo "string" | command
```

with the obvious exception that the latter uses a pipeline, which means you cannot meaningfully use it with `read` in particular. A common workaround is to use the `set` builtin to capture tokens from a string or an external command:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
set -- $line   # no quotes
IFS=$oldIFS
c1=$1
c2=$2
c3=$3
c4=$4
shift; shift; shift; shift
rest="$*"    # loses spacing / quoting
```

Another workaround is to use a loop which iterates just once; this may seem elegant at first, but can lead to rather clunky code if the body of the pseudo-loop is long or complex.

```
echo "$line" |
while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 rest; do
    : stuff which uses those variables
done
```

This works around the problem that `echo stuff | read variable` will run `read` in a child process and thus immediately forget the value of `variable` -- the body of the `while` loop is all the same process in which the `read` happened, and so the values of the variables it initialized are visible inside the loop.

Another, similar workaround is to delegate the reading and procesIng to a function;

```
process () {
    IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 rest
    : stuff which uses those variables
}

echo "$line" | process
```

Whether this is clunky or elegant depends a lot on what happens in the function. If it's neatly encapsulated, it can be rather attractive; but if you end up passing in a bunch of unrelated variables (or worse, modifying globals inside the function!) it can be quite the opposite.

Comment: The function did look very elegant and well thought out. In future projects I will probably use something more like this. However, the class I am in is more about learning the basics of UNIX. I know makes it so much harder to execute task. I ended up using the while loop. I will edit my post and show how the code ended up looking. Thanks

Comment: *"[...] with the obvious exception that the latter uses a pipeline, which means you cannot meaningfully use it with read in particular."*. This is not necessarily true and the problem is not with the pipeline per se but how a particular shell implements the pipe (see also [Shell Command Language, C.2.12 Shell Execution Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_12)). *...*

Comment: *...* In `ksh`, unlike `bash`,  the last command *is* run in the same process which means `bar=; echo foo | read bar; echo "[$bar]"` will work as expected and happily return `[foo]`. Since the question is specific to `ksh` all the workaround-ing is not really needed. Then again, it's definitely good to explain that you cannot rely on this behaviour seeing how many `bash`-questions revolve around this "problem".

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks for the update -- I was hoping somebody who actually knows `ksh` would stop by and comment.